Would there be a syntactic sugar -like way in Swift to make a "default member" of a struct (as if "hidden fields" added to a type)?
You have
typealias Stringish = String
var x: Stringish
func examp() {
    x = "yo"
    print(x)
}

and you have a zillion Stringish in your code base. You suddenly realize you need something more like
struct StringBonus {
    var value: String
    var version: Int
}
typealias Stringish = StringBonus

which is fine but you have to replace "x" everywhere with "x.value", as it were.
x.value = "yo"
print(x.value)
etc etc etc
var x: Stringish = tedious default value
etc etc etc

It would be incredible if you could still refer to x normally,
x = 69

but also access the "hidden" fields,
x.version = 2

Can anyone think of a way to make a struct "default" to one of the fields, or indeed a trick approach that achieves the same result.
I guess the amazing @resultBuilder would be impressive but I can't see a way to have a free-form resultBuilder inline (where the "x" is).
Maybe someone has a way.

I'd say typealias Stringish = String is a bad design in the first place, and you shouldn't have done that. You would be able to do this to a very limited extent with @dynamicMemberLookup and the ExpressibleByXXX protocols.

@dynamicMemberLookup FTW!  Will check it out thanks

@Sweeper @ dynamicMemberLookup is amazing, it's yet another thing i had never heard of until I saw yourself mentioning it on SO.  I may be mistaken but I don't think it can precisely let you access (this example) x.value as x, but it is amazing for similar stuff!

It allows you to write x.someProperty directly, instead of x.value.someProperty. I thought you were asking about a general case - this is indeed not that useful for Strings.

It just occured to me that if you try to do exactly what i ask here with an array, rather than a string - hence, "How to add hidden fields to a string variable, but, still be able to use the variable with adding '.value; ..." in fact it's trivial!  You just add subscript#index to the struct !!!  doh!

This isn’t quite the answer you are looking for, but you can simplify the initialization of your object using ExpressibleByStringLiteral:
struct Foo: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    let value: String 
    let count: Int
    
    init(value: String, count: Int = 0) {
        self.value = value 
        self.count = count
    }
    
    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value: value)
    }
}

let foo: Foo = "bar"
print(foo)              // Foo(value: "bar", count: 0)
print(foo.value)        // bar

There is an equivalent ExpressibleByStringInterpolation (but the implementation is a little more complicated, so I will not go down that rabbit hole).

The above tackles the initialization of your object. But, if we wanted to access the value without referencing the property, theoretically, we could implement our own type that conforms to StringProtocol, but I would advise against it because:

that has a pretty extensive number of methods that you would need to implement, so that’s a pretty heavy lift;

to my eye, that is for something that is inherently a “string type” (like Substring is), not just some random model type for which you want to enjoy String-like behaviors; and

most importantly, Apple explicitly advises against doing so:

Do not declare new conformances to StringProtocol.

And when Apple advises against stuff like this, it sometimes is not only “this is generally not a good idea” but “things will break if you do this”.


In short, I would advise against adopting StringProtocol yourself.

I would not recommend conforming to StringProtocol. Its documentation says explicitly not to conform to it.

Ah, I thought about tediously conforming to StringProtocol but I (perhaps incorrectly) thought you could not then just use the naked variable "x", when you wanted, and x.details when you wanted that.  I'll give it a go!

@Sweeper – Yes, you are right. The documentation is quite explicit on this. I've revised my answer to be more explicit that this theoretical possibility really is quite ill-advised.

@Fattie – While I suggested that possibility, Apple explicitly advises us to not do so. And when Apple advises against stuff like that, it sometimes is not only “this is generally not a good idea” but “things will break if you do this”. (I had this problem back in the day of NSURLConnection where docs suggested nice, abstract protocol conformance, but in reality, the brittle implementation behind the scenes broke it.) Anyway, hopefully the ExpressibleByStringLiteral (and possibly ExpressibleByStringInterpolation) solves half of your problem, the initialization.

@Rob 4 sure, it's worth trying for fun.  I am just now trying to discover what the hell conformance I am missing !

it's an awfully long list, unfortunately I don't have the time for now ..

It's a great pity there isn't an "ExpressibleByString" :/

FWIW, your question includes the example x = 69. That would beg for ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral (or ExpressibleByFloatLiteral).

It looks like you could just conform to StringProtocol and it all works. Unfortunately I have run out of messing-around time and couldn't complete this. If you just right-click forward to the StringProtocol headers, I have conveniently done it in the identical order as the (current) headers. Anyone may feel free to edit this.
Note that any programmer experienced enough to know what a protocol is and how to look at the UIKit headers will know you Should Not Do This. So don't do it. Awesome though!

///It is a String with convenient hidden fields.
struct Stringer: StringProtocol {
    var value: String
    var someHandyInt: Int?
    
    init(_ value: String) { self.value = value }
    init(stringLiteral value: String) { self.value = value }
    
    var utf8: String.UTF8View { value.utf8 }
    var utf16: String.UTF16View { value.utf16 }
    var unicodeScalars: String.UnicodeScalarView { value.unicodeScalars }
    func hasPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> Bool { value.hasPrefix(prefix) }
    func hasSuffix(_ suffix: String) -> Bool { value.hasSuffix(suffix) }
    func lowercased() -> String { value.lowercased() }
    func uppercased() -> String { value.uppercased() }
    
    init<C, Encoding>(decoding codeUnits: C, as sourceEncoding: Encoding.Type) where C : Collection, Encoding : _UnicodeEncoding, C.Element == Encoding.CodeUnit {
        value = String(decoding: codeUnits, as: sourceEncoding)
    }
    
    init(cString nullTerminatedUTF8: UnsafePointer<CChar>) {
        value = String(cString: nullTerminatedUTF8)
    }
    
    init<Encoding>(decodingCString nullTerminatedCodeUnits: UnsafePointer<Encoding.CodeUnit>, as sourceEncoding: Encoding.Type) where Encoding : _UnicodeEncoding {
        value = String(decodingCString: nullTerminatedCodeUnits, as: sourceEncoding)
    }
    
    func withCString<Result>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<CChar>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result {
        try value.withCString(body)
    }
    
    func withCString<Result, Encoding>(encodedAs targetEncoding: Encoding.Type, _ body: (UnsafePointer<Encoding.CodeUnit>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result where Encoding : _UnicodeEncoding {
        try value.withCString(encodedAs: targetEncoding, body)
    }
    
    func index(before i: String.Index) -> String.Index { value.index(before: i) }
    func index(after i: String.Index) -> String.Index { value.index(after: i) }
    subscript(position: String.Index) -> Character { get { value[position] } }
    
    func formIndex(before i: inout Self.Index) { value.formIndex(before: &i) }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Self.Index) { value.formIndex(after: &i) }
    
    mutating func write(_ string: String) { value = string }
    func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream { value.write(to: &target) }
    var startIndex: String.Index { return value.startIndex }
    var endIndex: String.Index { return value.endIndex }
    var description: String { return value }
}

